# Live Wallpaper + bitmap + canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

Helo everyone! I have this live wallpaper in witch I try to show a bitmap trough a canvas (the drawable resource is a 400k 1900x1200 jpg). It force-closes and I don't get why (it's my first Android project).  These are the "important" bits:

```
    wallEngine() { // CONSTRUCTOR   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                            mStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();


                            Log.v(Logcat, "Contructor ok");

                        }
                //====================================== INIT
                        private final Runnable mDrawWall = new Runnable() { //=========== RUN
                            public void run() {
                                drawFrame();
                            }
                        };

   void drawFrame() {

                           final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();                                         
                           Canvas c = null;
                           try {
                                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                                if (c != null) {
                                    // draw something
                                    updatePhysics();
                                    doDraw(c);
                                }
                            } finally {
                                if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                            }

                            // Reschedule the next redraw
                            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawWall);
                            if (mVisible) {
                                mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawWall, 5000);
                            }
                        }


    private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {                                                                                    
                      //backgroundImage.prepareToDraw();                                                    
                    canvas.drawBitmap(this.backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);                                                                    
                        }


public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

                            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);                      surfaceHolder.setFormat(android.graphics.PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);        

                            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            options.inPurgeable = true;

                            this.backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
                                com.misca.livewallpapers.parang.R.drawable.a, options);

                            //backgroundImage.prepareToDraw();
                            //setTouchEventsEnabled(true);
                            Log.v(Logcat, "onCreate ok");
                        }
```

And the logcat errors when i try to run it on my phone are :

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722): java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:957)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:983)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at com.misca.livewallpapers.parang.liveWallpaper$wallEngine.doDraw(liveWallpaper.java:115)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at com.misca.livewallpapers.parang.liveWallpaper$wallEngine.drawFrame(liveWallpaper.java:75)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at com.misca.livewallpapers.parang.liveWallpaper$wallEngine.onSurfaceChanged(liveWallpaper.java:157)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.updateSurface(WallpaperService.java:590)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.attach(WallpaperService.java:654)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:878)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3848)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-23 00:26:42.309: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7722):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you! :)

=======================
News:

```
                        private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {                                                                               
                        //backgroundImage.prepareToDraw();                         
                        if(this.backgroundImage!=null)
                        canvas.drawBitmap(this.backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
                        else
                        Log.v(Logcat, "null");

                    }
```

And seems the bitmap is null. Now i'm working with a 480x800 to ensure there are no memory problems. The app doesn't crash anymore with the if statement (empty black screen)

Comment: Have you ensured that the backgroundImage member is not null after it's instantiated during onCreate? If so, it seems like the image is being recycled and so the image reference is invalidated, hence the NullPointerException.

Comment: you're right! it's null, thank you. Any beter way to load it into the bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried scaling the bitmap to fit the canvas?  Do this in onSurfaceChanged, so you'll know the width and height to use.
You should check that your bitmap is being decoded correctly.  It doesn't matter that your resource is 400K--that's a very big bitmap to try to load into memory.  You only have 16 meg of heap...that bitmap is about 9 meg (4 bytes/pixel ARGB_8888).  George

Comment: I've actually done the rescale, in onSurfaceCheanged, like this :                           
               backgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(backgroundImage, width, height, true); . How can i test the bitmap loading? Thank you :)

Comment: the bitmap seems to be null, no loading there! i'm missing something

Comment: @Misca I would start by scaling the resource itself: make a smaller jpeg.  There is a way to scale the resource as it's being loaded, but I forget exactly how it's done; if I can find it, I'll leave another comment. I would never try to load a bitmap that big into memory.

Comment: now i'm using a 800x480 jpg and still the bitmap doesn't load. I've also tried with options.inDensity = 120;

Comment: @Misca Hmmm.  Feels like something squirrelly is going on.  Suggest breaking things up to make them very step-by-step, to make sure each piece of the puzzle fits.  Here's some code that works for me: mContext = getApplicationContext(); mRes = mContext.getResources();
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mRes, R.drawable.myimage, mOpts);
(This way you can make sure your resources are good; not sure what else to suggest except converting file to png)  Also--your bitmap should be 480x800 not 800x480.

Comment: @Misca in general, if you want to scale a resource as it's being loaded use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize

Comment: Thank you for your responeses, you where very fast :)

Comment: @Misca pleased to be of service.  When you track down the problem, please let us know what it was.  Also, um, I don't think you should be setting inPurgeable to true -- it's safer to recycle the bitmap manually as described here: http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/scarce-commodities-google-android-memory-and-bitmaps/

Comment: Actually the main problem was pretty dum: the autogenerated R didn't saw the drawabels trough the xml bitmaps so i've deleted the resources and added new jpg's with drag'n'drop from the explorer. I also had a lot of other problems, some of them where also treated by you :)